# Strange partition persists after reinstall

Tags: partitioning

I was trying to install DBAN on a USB, but instead accidentally installed it to `/boot`, overwriting my existing boot partition. This obviously ruined everything, and I googled what to do and the response was basically "you can't fix this, reinstall Linux", so I did (thankfully I have backups), but after reinstalling (a few times, actually), I still see this strange ghost "DBAN" disk in the file explorer. I can't find it on the filesystem anywhere, but it shows up in the file explorer GUI. When I click on it, I get the following message:

```
Error mounting /dev/sda2 at /media/alex/DBAN: Command-line `mount -t "iso9660" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,mode=0400,dmode=0500" "/dev/sda2" "/media/alex/DBAN"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda2,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.
```

What does this mean? How do I make this strange ghost disk go away, and should I be concerned about it?

Answer (score 0):

I would try doing `sudo umount /media/alex/DBAN`. It sounds as if the install media had mounted itself, and had not unmounted after reboot. *iso9660* refers to an optical disk's file systems, which in most cases is the installation media.

Also, try checking out your partitions in *gparted*. That may be able to give some more insight to why it's appearing in the first place.

Comment: I got umount: /media/alex/DBAN: mountpoint not found when I ran that command

When i opened gparted, the ghost disk disappeared from file viewer as long as gparted was open, then reappeared when i closed it

Comment: gparted is supposed to do that. From the error that your file manager gave us, it does appear to trying to mount something that may or may not exist. If we could have a screenshot of your gparted, we could see what partition that may be.